# IBM DB2, SQL and Java PreparedStatement. How to: SELECT WHERE ROWID=

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

```
    String updateSQL = "UPDATE FILE_CLOB_VERSION SET WS_ACHIEVED = ? WHERE ROWID = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(updateSQL);   
    ...
    stmt.setString(1, "PUBLISHED");
    stmt.setRowId(2,new RowId() {

        @Override
        public byte[] getBytes() {
            return "4fa78fb773723b13e90401255bdc0100000000001201".getBytes();
        }
    });
```

The above is not working, getting :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

**java/sql/PreparedStatement.setRowId(ILjava/sql/RowId;)**

I tried to use String:

```
    stmt.setString(2, "4fa78fb773723b13e90401255bdc0100000000001201");
```

**Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][1083][10403] Unallowed convertion.**

I also tried to change the updateSQL:

```
String updateSQL = "... ROWID = ROWID(X?)";
```

and use setString ... no luck. If you query the database without preparedstatement outside of java environment, the query would look like this:

```
UPDATE FILE_CLOB_VERSION SET WS_ACHIEVED = 'PUBLISHED' WHERE ROWID = ROWID(X'4fa78fb773723b13e90401255bdc0100000000001201')
```

How should my preparedstatement look like?

The ROWID column is of datatype ROWID:

**COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME**

**ROWID 1111    ROWID**

Comment: Does this help? [ROWIDs in JDBC with the IBM DB2 Driver for JDBC and SQLJ](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc%2Fdoc%2Fcjvjdrwi.htm)

Comment: Maybe u should use String updateSQL = "... ROWID = ROWID(X'?')";

Comment: Had already seen that before, bu no, no help :(

Comment: No, I believe I have already tried that plus you do not usually quote strings in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
stmt.setBytes(2, "4fa78fb773723b13e90401255bdc0100000000001201".getBytes());
```

Comment: Just did: Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -804, SQLSTATE: 07002, SQLERRMC: 09

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sqlstatevalues.htm

for the codes and their meaning

Comment: On which platform are you running the code and what's the default encoding? If it's something esoteric(iSeries or the like) or the database expects the bytes in a non-ASCII compatible encoding, you could try to specify it explicitly, e.g. getBytes("ASCII") or getBytes("Cp1047")